# Проблема с session start

Tags: php

Есть файл db.php . Как в нем расположить session_start(); что бы интерпретатор
не выдавал ошибку : Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by 
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already send

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require "libs/rb.php";
  R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'test', 'password' );

?>
```

Comment: А где-то ранее вы уже вызывали  session_start?

Comment: как в вопросе, так и надо. другое део, что скорее всего этот файл тоже где-то раньше реквайрится. А зачем вообще открывать сессию в файле подключения к базе??

Comment: А мне кажется что дело все в банальном варнинге или нотисе выше, то есть что то уже выдавали в headers. Перед этим варнингом есть что то еще?

Comment: Kirill,что бы проверить пользователя на логин на сайте

Comment: Дмитрий, что такое варнинг и headers(Только начал учить php)

Comment: сообщения об ошибках. Warning и тому подобное.

Comment: Нет, только эти 2 ошибки

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N удалите пробел перед `session_start();` ` headers already sent by ...` значит что у вас выводится раньше что угодно - пробел, символ, буква, перенос строки, табуляция стоит и т.п..

Comment: Убрал, не работает

Comment: @E_R_H_A_N дайте скриншот файла в каком-то редакторе. Вы данный файл где-то подключаете?

Comment: @InDevX пробел? серьёзно? с каких это пор символы кода стали "выводимыми" данными?

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk подумал `<?php` а написал другое, когда заметил уже нельза было редактировать. А вот второй вопрос интересный. Буквально неделю назад ломали голову - откуда эта ошибка вылазит, в итоге оказалось что из-за вот этого - https://prnt.sc/qgg2m6, при этом в обычном редакторе её/его (не знаю что это вообще) - не видно, но в jira (откуда скрин) отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема состоит в том, что session_start() нужно вызвать ДО каких либо выводов данных, если ответ уже начал отправляться юзеру - понятно что сессию запустить уже нельзя

Comment: Что за люди ставят минус.Человек своими словами, но по сути верно ответил.

Comment: @noname2019 а какими тут словами ещё ответить если не понятно что там в коде делается) мало ли что выполняется перед стартом сессии)